# Getting syntax error when using CASE to check if column is more than 0, else use other column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to use the CASE function to check if the `discount_price` column is more than 0, if so then select everything where `discount_price >= 60` else select everything where `price >= 60`.

But for some reason I get a syntax error.

The error:

```
Something is wrong with the used syntax ')
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM `product_variants` WHERE 
(CASE WHEN `discount_price` > 0 THEN (SELECT * FROM product_variants WHERE discount_price >= 60) ELSE (SELECT * FROM product_variants WHERE price >= 60))
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using mysql

Comment: Your intended logic is not so clear, and a small minimal sample data set would greatly help your question.

Comment: The error itself means that you have lost final END in the CASE operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need a case statement, everything could be in one query with some logic:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM product_variants
WHERE discount_price >= 60
OR (discount_price <= 0 AND price >= 60)
```

Assuming `discount_price` cannot be negative, the second condition can be `(discount_price = 0 AND price >= 60)`.

EDIT: As [@Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) stated, (discount_price > 0 AND discount_price >= 60) has no sense, fixed that.